# Scale scanned PDF without resampling image layer

Tags: macos, unix, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have a batch of PDFs (about 80,000 files) that consist of scanned pages.  The pixel size of the image layer is consistent with 300dpi, but seems to be set to 72dpi.  As a result the page size is showing something like 46x35 inches.  I need to adjust these files so they register as 8.5 x 11, or whatever their natural size is, and I need to be able to script the process so I can leave this to churn on 80,000 documents (2-5 pages per document.)

I'd like to avoid resampling the image layer since that would potentially add loss, and slow the process down significantly.  I've tried:

```
convert -density 300x300 input.pdf output.pdf
```

But it resamples the images.  I've tried different variants on ghostscript such as

```
gs \
  -o output.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
  -dMonoImageResolution=300 \
   input.pdf
```

That generates a file, but it seems unchanged, and and still registers as oversized.  Also, the pages are different sizes and orientations.  So forcing them all to one size/orientation won't work.

(FYI, really I wouldn't care, but the next step is to have Acrobat Pro OCR all these files, and its OCR chokes on anything over 45 inches.)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to reset the resolution setting, rather than actually resample it. I should think GhostScript would be the way to go, rather than ImageMagick - though I'm afraid I don't know how. Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

PDF is a resolution independent format, so the resolution of the images and so on is pretty irrelevant. The 'natural size' of the pages is whatever Acrobat says it is, this is gathered from the MediaBox (or CropBox) information which is in the file.

It sounds to me like the original conversion to PDF is at fault, and the files genuinely are the (media) size they claim to be now.

I suspect that you can probably get the result you need; you 'simply' need to resize the document. The problem is that this isn't trivial where the media sizes differ (which you say they do).

However before going further I suggest you take a file which you want to be 8.5x11 and try this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 \
   -dFIXEDMEDIA \
   -dPDFFitPage \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
    input.pdf
```

This will fix the media being used at 8.5x11 and tell Ghostscript to resize the document to fit the page (by calculating and applying a scale factor). It should not affect the image data except for compression, if there are colour images we might need to worry about JPEG artefacts but that can be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 2):

cpdf -scale-pages usletterportrait in.pdf -o out.pdf

Doesn't touch the page content other than to wrap it in a transformation matrix to do the scaling, and scales the media/crop/art/bleed/trim boxes too.

(Commercial, I'm afraid:

http://www.coherentpdf.com/

Disclaimer: I wrote it.)

Comment: At least put a screenshot in which you apply the operation in question … :P

Answer (score 1):

Modify your original `gs` command like this:

```
gs \
  -o output.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dPDFFitPage \
  -g6120x7920 \
   input.pdf
```

Then check 2 things:

1. Page dimensions are displaying as 'letter' (or 612x792 pts, or 8.5x11 in) now.
2. File size is only marginally different from original one (indicating that no resampling of page image has happened).

If the input is scanned documents in grayscale only (as it seems to be), there is no need for setting `-dDownSample*Images` or for setting `-d*ImageResolution`.